Why is the tensor product not a multilinear application?
I was studying multilinear algebra and I wanted to have a good understanding for relativity. I started studying multilinear applications, which are kind of like a natural extension of linear applications, but instead of having one input element they have several. Then I studied the tensor product, and I saw that it was an operation for transforming multilinear applications into linear ones. My question is, if the notation is $$\otimes : V_1 \times V_2 \times ... \times V_n \rightarrow V_1 \otimes V_2 \otimes ... \otimes V_n$$ is actually taking n vector spaces and returning only one, isn't it? I don't understand why it's not a multilinear application. Then, I understand that the space that it generates is called tensor space and that the elements that compose that space are called tensors, and another question would be, why tensors are multilinear applications? Because, like vectors, they can be operated with them as applications? I have found in some places that the "mathematical" reason is $$ V_1 \otimes V_2 \otimes ... \otimes V_n \rightarrow W,$$ but that to my understanding is a linear application, because $$ V_1 \otimes V_2 \otimes ... \otimes V_n$$ must be understood as a single vector space although it seems that in notation it can be more than one, right?

In fact, the tensor product map $\otimes$  is multi linear. Furthermore, tensors are multi linear as they act multi linearly on the relevant Cartesian products of dual spaces.

another notation I saw was $T:V_1 \times V_2 \times ... \times V_n \rightarrow R$ and I don't understand it either. The tensor is the result of the scalar product, and it is the tensor product that takes n spaces and "converts" them into one, isn't it? the tensor is simply the result of that. Wouldn't it be like saying that the scalar number of the dot product is $\langle \cdot , \cdot\rangle : V_1 \times V_2  -> R}$? that's actually the operation of the dot product, not the result itself, right?

@ValterMoretti Which one do you mean? The tensor product?

Yes, your tensor product map.

@ValterMoretti so any tensor product is a multilinear map?

A physics oriented intro is here: http://www.pmaweb.caltech.edu/Courses/ph136/yr2012/1201.1.K.pdf

The tensor product map
$$\otimes : V_1\times \cdots\times V_n \to V_1\otimes \cdots \otimes V_n$$
is multi linear as the codomain is a linear space and the map is separately linear in each entry.
Every tensor $t\in V_1\otimes \cdots \otimes V_n$ is a multilinear functional since it is a multi linear  map
$$t : V^*_1\otimes \cdots \otimes V^*_n  \to \mathbb{K}$$
where the latter is the common field of all involved linear spaces.
(See my lecture notes https://moretti.maths.unitn.it/tensori.pdf)

Thank you, your notes are really good and intuitive.

When we say that a tensor is a multilinear transformation, do we mean the whole tensor, such that $T= T^{ij} e_i \otimes e_j$ or just the components of the tensor $T^{ij}$ ?

The whole tensor: each $e_k$ is seen as a linear map on the dual space $V^*$…
